# Small filters are measurable

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I want to show, that a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $\omega$ (considered as a subset of $2^\omega$), which is small, is measurable.

I found a lemma (without proof), that every small set is null. So, if $\mathcal{F}$ is small, then $\mu(\mathcal{F})=0$. To show, that $\mathcal{F}$ is measurable, one must show that $\mu(\mathcal{F}\triangle B)=0$ for a Borel set B. Now, since the empty set is a Borel set, it follows $\mu(\mathcal{F}\triangle \emptyset)=\mu(\mathcal{F})=0$.

Is this correct? I also want to know why every small set is null?

A set $H\subseteq 2^\omega$ is small, if there exists a partition $\langle I_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ of $\omega$ into disjoint finite intervals and a sequence $\langle J_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ such that

1. $J_n\subseteq 2^{I_n}$
2. $\sum_{n\in\omega}|J_n|*2^{-|I_n|}<\infty$
3. $H\subseteq \{x\in 2^\omega:\exists^{\infty}n\ x\restriction I_n \in J_n\}$

A measure on a Polish $X$ space will be refered as a function $\mu:BOREL(X)\rightarrow [0,1]$ s.t.

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0,\mu(X)=1$
2. If $\{A_n:n\in\omega\}\subseteq BOREL(X)$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets, then $\mu(\cup_{n\in\omega}A_n)=\sum_{n\in\omega}A_n$
3. $\mu$ is nonatomic
4. $\mu$ is translation invariant
5. for every $A\in BOREL(X)$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compact set and an open set $U$ such that $K\subseteq A \subseteq U$ and $\mu(U\cap K^{c})<\epsilon$

Measurable sets are defined as $MEASURABLE(X)=\{A:\exists B\in BOREL(X) \mu(A\triangle B)=0\}$

Comment: What is a "small" filter? In your desired conclusion, does "measurable" mean that the corresponding set of reals is Lebesgue measurable? If you already know that $\mu(\mathcal F)=0$ doesn't that immediately imply that $\mathcal F$ is measurable (since "measurable" ought to mean simply that $\mu(\mathcal F)$ is _defined at all_)?

Comment: The filter on $\omega$ will be identified as a subset of $\omega$ via characteristic functions. The definition of a small set can be found in "Bartoszynski, Tomek & Judah, Haim Set theory: On the structure of the real line" in chapter 4. I will add it here later.

Comment: So I take it you only want answers from people who have that book?

Comment: Of course not. I added the definitions.

Comment: It seems that the two $|A|$ notations mean something different (for subsets of $\omega$ and of functions, respectively). Could you elucidate that?

Comment: I should have mentioned, that the sets $I_n$ have to be finite. It sould be clear now?

Comment: That clears $|I_n|$ up, but not $|J_n|$. Would the last one be the measure of the set of functions? (Btw, don't forget to notify via @name, that's why I only saw this now.)

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Why? The number of functions from $I_n$ into 2 is finite since $I_n$ is finite. So, as $J_n$ is a subset of $2^{I_n}$, $|J_n|$ simply means the number of elements in this set.

Comment: In fact, $2^{I_n}\geq|J_n|$.

Comment: got me. Now I'll start thinking! :-)

Comment: Are you studying [Lemma 1.10](https://books.google.com/books?id=mPLpBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA181) from Judah, Bartozsynski: Measure and category - filters on $\omega$? (As I have mentioned to you in comment to another question, it is usually good to include source of the problem. Even more so if you are studying some specialized topic.)

Comment: In the text I mentioned in the previous comment, [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) is mentioned in connection with the fact that small sets are have measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a measure to be *translation invariant*, you should have an underlying group structure, not just a Polish space. In the case of $2^\omega$, this is the countable power of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so indeed you have one. And there is only one Borel probability measure on $2^\omega$ that is translation invariant. This [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) $\mu$ is characterized by
$$
\mu(\{x\in 2^\omega : x \restriction I = f \})=2^{-|I|},\qquad (*)
$$
for every finite $I\subset \omega$ and $f\in 2^I$.

Now it is enough to see that 
$$
\{x\in 2^\omega:\exists^{\infty}n\ x\restriction I_n \in J_n\}=\bigcap_m\bigcup_{n>m}\{x\in 2^\omega:x\restriction I_n \in J_n\}
$$
has arbitrarily small measure. For this, first fix $m$ and calculate:
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{n>m}\{x\in 2^\omega:x\restriction I_n \in J_n\}\right)\leq \sum_{n>m}\mu(\{x\in 2^\omega: x\restriction I_n \in J_n\})
$$
and this last term equals
$
\sum_{n>m}|J_n|\cdot 2^{-|I_n|}
$
by $(*)$. Since the full sum converges, you only have to choose $m$ big enough.

Comment: How did you derive equation $(*)$? When introducing the measure $\mu$ as the product measure on $2^\omega$ of the measures $\mu_i$ on $i\in\omega$, $(*)$ becomes clear to me. Finally you apply the continuity proberty $\lim\mu(A_n)=\mu(A)$ for $A_n\uparrow A$ using $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n>1}\{x\in 2^\omega:x\restriction I_n \in J_n\}\right)<\infty$

Comment: And the $\mu_i$ are defined as $\mu_{s(i)}(\{i\})=\mu_{s(i)}(\{\{i\}\})=\frac{1}{2}$ in my comment above.

Comment: @peer I'm not sure what the subscript $s(i)$ means there. Nevertheless, you can find the whole treatment of such measures in Kechris' [Classical Descriptive Set Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387943749), chap.17. There, property (*) is stated for $I$ an initial segment of $\omega$, but it should be easy to derive this form. For the last displayed inequality I'm just using subadditivity.

Comment: $s(i)$ just means the successor of $i$ defined as $s(i)=\{i,\{i\}\}$, since we want to define a measure for each element of $\omega$ and $\omega$ is defined as the smallest set containing the empty set and with $i$ also $s(i)$. What i wrote might not be correct. I meant $\mu_i(\{0\})=\mu_i(\{1\})=\frac{1}{2}$ for $i\in\omega$.

Comment: @peer Your last statement is sensible. Btw, the successor of $i$ is $i\cup\{i\}$, which is usually different from you wrote

Comment: Can you please add a remark on the definition of measurable sets? Since Borel(X) is already a $\sigma$-algebra, why does the textbook say that when $\mu$ is a measure, it can be extended to a $\sigma$-algebra defined by Measurable(X) as at the end of my first post? Clearly, $Borel(X)\subseteq Measurable(X)$

Comment: @peer If $A\subseteq B\in \mathit{Borel}(X)$ and $\mu(B)=0$, then $\mu(A)=0$. But if $B$ is uncountable, there are many $A$ that are not Borel. Hence you $\mathit{Measurable}(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra including  $\mathit{Borel}(X)$ and the null sets.

Comment: And the symmetric difference of a set A and a Borel-set is Borel? Otherwise it would not be defined.